# Dice Expected Value - Game of chance

Tags: dice, expected-value

Suppose you repeatedly roll a fair six-sided dice until you roll a 1 (and then you stop). Every time you roll a 2, you lose `x` points, and every time you roll a 6, you win `y` points. You do not win or lose any points if you roll a 3,4, or 5.

What is the expected number of points (as a function of `x,y` ) you will have when you stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the answer be $E$.  When we throw the die, we note four possible outcomes. Either you get a $1$, ending the game, or you get a $2$ and lose x points, or you get a $6$ and get $y$ points, or you get $3,4,5$ and just restart.  It follows that $$E=\frac 16\times 0+\frac 16\times (E-x)+\frac 16\times (E+y)+\frac 12\times E\implies \boxed {E=y-x}$$

Informally:  there are three relevant outcomes (ignoring the ones that change nothing) and all are equally likely.  By symmetry, you expect it to take three (relevant) tosses to get a $1$.  Thus you expect to get two relevant throws before the game ends.  By symmetry, you must expect to get one of each of the two other relevant throws.

Comment: since by 2 we lose x points the sign of x should be negative in your answer though. Thanks

Comment: but should it be -(E+x) or (E-x)?

Comment: @Soyol  Yes, I missed that $x$ was a loss.  I will edit.